# Will .delay(2000) delay a jQuery Ajax call?

Tags: jquery

By adding the `delay(1000)` and `delay(2000)` will that correctly delay the return from the `doAction` ajax call? I checked the spec and I see delay used with other jQuery such as `$("div.first").slideUp(300).delay(800).fadeIn(400);`  However I am just not sure about `async = false` ajax calls.

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                traditional: true,
                url: '/adminTask/doAction',
                async: false,
                data: parms,
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#rdy_msg").text("Completed: " + id).delay(1000);
                },
                error: function () {
                    var cdefg = data;
                }
            }).delay(2000)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delay is used with animations and will change the time until the next function in the chain executes.

from the docs (emphasis is mine)

> Added to jQuery in version 1.4, the .delay() method allows us to delay the execution of functions that follow it in the queue. *It can be used with the standard effects queue or with a custom queue*

In your case you are probably looking for a simple setTimeout('function', delay);

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp

Comment: oh, javascript.  what i wouldn't give for sleep().

Comment: I see this setTimeout() - executes a code some time in the future. How about just a stop and wait in javascript. Is there such a thing?

Comment: @MarieMarie Can I ask real quick why you would want to do that (I presume you are waiting for something else to happen?) what is it that you are waiting to happen?

Comment: I want the user to see a message before the next action starts

Comment: And what is the next action? Is it inside your success callback or elsewhere?

Comment: Either way you still want to use setTimeout. Put your code that displays the message into a function and then call it using setTimeout. The script will pause for however many ms you specify, then display your message - then continue executing.

Comment: http://w3fools.com/#js_timing.  [This](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Window.setTimeout) is a better link.

Comment: @ Andy E :-) I didn't even see that - it's the first link that came up after a quick google. To be fair I did say to use a function.

Comment: setTimeout and setInterval totally are functions.

Comment: @Kerin I meant as the first argument of each of those functions - call another function, don't write a string of js to be parsed

Comment: You can avoid the eval()-style difficulties of setTimeout by using anonymous functions, like so:

var steaksauce = setTimeout(function(){
//additional code that inherits variable scope here
},500);

Comment: It isn't really any less readable than standard braces if you indent properly.  :)